# Displaying JSON answer in an html page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have no background in JavaScript and/or Angular but I need to use it for a research project. Shortly, I need to display on a webpage the JSON which is the answer from another component.

Here is the flow:

From the user interface clicking on Submit button a JSON file is sent to another component which does something and returns a JSON. This answer JSON should be displayed on a webpage.

The submit button is as follows and happens in the page named page2.html:

```
<button name="topage1" class="button-submit" ng-click="generateJSON()">Submit</font></button>
```

The method `generateJSON()` has the following code:

```
$scope.generateJSON = function(){
   generateIdForComponents();
   addRestrictions();
   // REST
   data = angular.toJson($scope.schema, true);
   headers= {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
   };

$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/re/z3', data, {headers:headers}).
    then(function(response) {
        console.log("Merge post ", response.data);
        $scope.greeting = response.data;
    });
}});
```

The routing is as follows:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/topage1", {
      templateUrl : "page1.html",
      controller : "page1Controller"
  })
  .when("/topage2", {
      templateUrl : "page2.html",
      controller : "page2Controller"
  })
  .when("/results", {
      templateUrl : "outputOffers.html",
      controller : "resultsController"
  })
  .otherwise({
      templateUrl : "page1.html",
      controller : "page1Controller"
   });
});
```

What code should I write such that the JSON is displayed on outputOffers.html.

Comment: Please share your HTML(outputOffers.html) code as well..

Comment: I don't have any yet! I don't know how to start.

Comment: Stop tagging with `angular` things releated to `angularjs`.

Comment: You should show the sample response output atleast to help you..

Comment: can you please create a basic structure on https://plnkr.co/edit/. we can try to complete it rather than creating entire structure from scratch from the code you have provided.

Comment: If you put the $http.post request in a method in a factory then store the response.data in a variable in the factory then this variable will be global and you can use it in your resultsController in order to use in your outputOffers.html file.

Comment: BTW, you have some error in the code with '</font>', where is the opening tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that in the callback of your `$scope.generateJSON` method, you redirect to the outputOffers results page (where you want to display the response json data) and you pass the json data as a parameter.

Then in your resultsController you can assign the json data (sent as a parameter) to a `$scope.greeting` variable to use in your outputOffers view.

You need the [routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) service to pass parameters between views and you will need to inject it into your resultsController.

You will also need the `$location` service in your page2Controller (in order to perform the redirect) so inject it as follows:

```
myApp.controller("page2Controller", function($scope, $location){...
```

Your generateJSON method in your page2 controller would look like this:

```
$scope.generateJSON = function(){
   generateIdForComponents();
   addRestrictions();
   // REST
   data = angular.toJson($scope.schema, true);
   headers= {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
   };

   $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/re/z3', data, {headers:headers}).
    then(function(response) {
        console.log("Merge post ", response.data);
        //redirect to the outputOffers view, passing the json data as a parameter
        $location.path('results').search({jsonData: response.data });
    });
}});
```

## resultsController

Firstly inject the `$routeParams` to your resultsController as follows so we can get any parameters sent with the url (replace `myApp` with the name of your app):

```
myApp.controller("resultsController", function($scope, $routeParams){...
```

Use an anonymous function in the resultsController which checks whether the jsonData parameter exists (which we sent from the page2 controller). If it does exist then we assign it to a `$scope.greeting` variable

```
(function() {
  if($routeParams.jsonData == null || $routeParams.jsonData === ""){
    //If the jsonData is not set or if it doesnt contain a value (i.e is the empty string) then redirect to the page2 view.
    $location.path('topage2'); 
  }else{ 
    //the jsonData parameter does exist so assign it to our scope.greeting variable so we can use it in our view.
    $scope.greeting = $routeParams.jsonData;
    //log the data to make sure it was passed as parameter:
    console.log($scope.greeting);
  }
})();
```

Then in the outputOffers.html view you can use the `$scope.greeting` variable.
For example if the json contains a "title" and a "message" property then we can do the following:

```
<p>{{greeting.title}}</p>
<p>{{greeting.message}}</p>
```

## Update:

After seeing a snippet of your json in your comment you could do the following to display it:

```
<div ng-repeat="g in greeting"> 
  <p>id: {{g.id}}</p>
  <p>clockspeed: {{g.offer.clockSpeed}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Off-topic: Why Enter does not work as new line in a Comment? It simply finishes my comment. On-topic: Now the redirecting works, however, my JSON is not displayed at all. The HTML code is: <div ng-repeat="g in greeting"> {{g}} </div> What I actually return is an array of JSON offers, which in the Python console looks like this: "[{\"id\": 1, \"components\": [\"hdfs\"], \"offer\": {\"appliesTo\": [], \"clockSpeed\": \"2.3 GHz\", \"currentGeneration\": \"Yes\", \"dedicatedEbsThroughput\": \"12000 Mbps\", \"description\": ...}}]" Should I loop through all JSON levels: id, offer, clockSpeed, etc.?

Comment: You would need to do something like  <div ng-repeat="g in greeting"> {{g.id}} </div> ... instead of just {{g}}... can you firstly try logging $scope.greeting in the console (in the resultsController) after you assign the jsonData to it... i.e 
    $scope.greeting = jsonData; console.log($scope.greeting); to make sure it was passed as a parameter

Comment: @MadalinaErascu Also your json looks like its not formatted properly. it looks like its accidentally double encoded. (it shouldnt have backslashes like that) It should look more like this: [{"id": 1, "components": ["hdfs"], "offer": {"appliesTo": [], "clockSpeed": "2.3 GHz", "currentGeneration": "Yes", "dedicatedEbsThroughput": "12000 Mbps"}}]

Comment: Tried this and also Amir's solution with no success. At least in this case, I have: "Can't find variable: jsonData
http://localhost:8080/MANeUveR-webui/static/app.js:711 – "<div ng-view=\"\" class=\"ng-scope\">" and the value of jsonData is not in the logs. I have here the main files used: app.js and outputoffers.html: https://plnkr.co/edit/XW78SuILkiCvk3uiZPUK?p=catalogue

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake (in resultsController) instead of $scope.greeting = jsonData; it should be  $scope.greeting = $routeParams.jsonData; I just tested this and it works...I will edit the answer so you can see.

Comment: This is now solved, however, issues at JSON display exits. The way outoutOffers.html is now (https://plnkr.co/edit/XW78SuILkiCvk3uiZPUK?p=catalogue) gives the error "[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: g in greeting, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: ". If I write "g in greeting track by $index" then "id: {{g.id}}" and "clockspeed: {{g.offer.clockSpeed}} "are written dozens on time in the output page. The values of g.id and g.offer.clockSpeed are not replaced

Comment: When I look at your json it looks like theres only one object in the array which may cause this error. Will there always be just one object in this array? If so then you can just assign greeting to the first element of the jsonData array as follows: $scope.greeting = $routeParams.jsonData[0]; Then in your html, dont use ng-repeat just say {{greeting.id}} and {{greeting.offer.clockSpeed}} etc.

Comment: I tried many versions, including your solution but it does not work. Here is what the output is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2luvlypscvls6rm/Screen%20Shot%202018-12-28%20at%2010.36.08%20AM.png?dl=0. The code is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/XW78SuILkiCvk3uiZPUK?p=catalogue. I'm wondering if outputOffers.html should not contain more than what you wrote. It seems it sees variable greeting as a simple string.

Comment: I've just looked at your page1 view and you are outputting variables with the following brackets. {[{componentName.name}]} This is different to what I do when using angularjs so maybe you have a different version. so can you try outputting your greeting variable as follows: {[{greeting.id}]} and {[{greeting.offer.clockSpeed}]}? also can you try declaring an empty greeting  variable before the anonymous function in resultsController like this: $scope.greeting = {};

Comment: I see why {{}} is not working now in your view to output variables. In app.js on line 4 i.e in these lines of code
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}'); it looks like you are changing the angular interpolated string symbols to {[{ }]} when normally by default they are {{}}. see more info on this link at the bottom: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate so you should be using {[{ }]} to output your variables in your app (as I said in my previous comment) so hopefully {[{greeting.id}]} etc should work.

Comment: This did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @MadalinaErascu That's great :)

Answer (score 0):

One option can be create a service which will contain two functions to store and to fetch the value. The function that stores the value will be placed in 'page2Controller'.
The function that fetches the value will be placed in resultsController.
Find below a short tutorial.

the service should look like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/topage1", {
      templateUrl : "page1.html",
      controller : "page1Controller"
  })
  .when("/topage2", {
      templateUrl : "page2.html",
      controller : "page2Controller"
  })
  .when("/results", {
      templateUrl : "outputOffers.html",
      controller : "resultsController"
  })
  .otherwise({
      templateUrl : "page1.html",
      controller : "page1Controller"
   });
});

app.service('greetingService', function() {
    this.greeting = '';
    this.store = function (greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }
    this.fetch = function () {
      return this.greeting;
    }
});
```

page2Controller should look like this:

```
app.controller('page2Controller', function($scope, greetingService) {
  $scope.generateJSON = function(){
   generateIdForComponents();
   addRestrictions();
   // REST
   data = angular.toJson($scope.schema, true);
   headers= {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
   };

$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/re/z3', data, {headers:headers}).
    then(function(response) {
        console.log("Merge post ", response.data);
        greetingService.store(response.data);
    });
}});
});
```

resultsController should look like this:

```
app.controller('resultsController ', function($scope, greetingService) {
  $scope.greeting = greetingService.fetch();
});
```

then, somewhere in your 'outputOffers.html' put this:

```
{{greeting}}
```